# How to set group headers in listview not selectable?

Tags: c#, listview, header

I need some help for my listview element, I want to use listview with groups. But i want to make the group headers not selectable, i want to use them as a separator?

How can I do this?

---

I've added `this.lstView.SelectedIndexChanged` event listener. Also I have two groups where I need every index from each item. If I debug the index with  `((ListViewItem)lstView.SelectedItems[0]).Index` in the event listener I get an exception if the group header is selected, so I want to disable the selecting of group headers.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

[alt text http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC16066.gif](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC16066.gif)

```
// Adds a new group that has a left-aligned header
listView1.Groups.Add(new ListViewGroup("List item text", HorizontalAlignment.Left));
```

You can find more information about it on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezh1batz.aspx

Comment: no this doesn't work, they are still selectable if i use keyboard to scroll through the list