# Make TListView group headers unclickable

Tags: delphi, listview, delphi-xe6, tlistview, listviewgroup

I have a TListView with groups. Is there a way to make the group headers unclickable, so that they act like simple separators? `TListGroupState` doesn't seem to contain an applicable flag. I've found "[How to set group headers in listview not selectable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227943/how-to-set-group-headers-in-listview-not-selectable-c)" which has no useful answer either.

**Edit:** By "unclickable" I mean that the items should not be hottracked and should not respond to being clicked.

Comment: Unclickable isn't really what you want. Of course you cannot stop the user clicking on them. What you want is for them to stop responding to being clicked.

Comment: You'll need to handle all by yourself as there is no [`state`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774769(v=vs.85).aspx) like `LVGS_ENABLED` or `LVGS_DISABLED`. That needs to manage clicking, hot tracking and possibly also drawing.

Comment: @TLama, can you make that an answer?

Comment: I was hoping for some more detailed answer, ideally with an example of all the necessary message handling. If I were you, I'd wait for a while :)

Comment: I don't want to put a lot of effort into that. If it were a 2 or 3 API calls - OK. But I wouldn't like to override lots of messages and owner-drawing.

Comment: @TLama, I waited for a while. :-)